# Magento 2.2.2 Differet Store Category page was give 404 error

Tags: category, magento2.2.2

Magento 2.2.2 website Category Page Give **404 Error** into **Different Store** , Into Default Store it is worked Fine .

I have `Reindex` Many time and also i have `cleared Cache` Many Times But No any kind of Solution Find .

Comment: Have you found anything in error log?

Comment: No , I does not found anything into log